# Is it possible to store a removed value in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi I am new to haskell and I was just wondering whether it was possible to store a value that has already been removed:

This is my code

```
input :: Integer -> String
input x = checklength $ intolist x

intolist 0 = []
intolist x = intolist (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10] 

checklength x = if length(x) >= 13 && length(x) <= 16 then doubleall 
(init(x)) else "Not valid length of credit card number" 

doubleall x = finalcheck $ final $ double (reverse (x))

double x = case x of
[]   -> []
[x]  -> if (x*2 < 10) then [x*2] else [x*2 `div` 10 + x*2 `mod` 10]
x:y:xs -> (if (x*2 < 10) then [x*2] else [x*2 `div` 10 + x*2 `mod` 10]) ++ 
y:double xs

final x = (sum x) * 9

finalcheck x = if (x `mod` 10 == ...... ) then "True" else "False"
```

My code basically takes an input as an integer such as 987564736264535. then makes this integer into a list of number such as [9,8,7..5]. Then it checks the length has to between 13 to 16 digits. If not you get an error statement. If the digits are between the required amount it will go into the doubeall function and remove the last number using (init). **the number removed is 5** in which it will double the numbers and reverse the list order. It will then sum the numbers together and multiple by 9. The final step that I have done part of is taking the last digit of the number that has already been summed together and multiplied by 9. So lets give and example lets say I get 456 then I use mod 10 to take the last number which is 6. **Now here is where I am having a problem in which I want to check whether this 6 is equal to the same number that was removed originally in the checklength function when I used init. So in the checklength function I removed the number 5 **

Thanks

Comment: Try editing your question to make the explanation of your logic more readable; as written it's very tedious.

Comment: Are you asking how to define a function `:: [a] -> ([a], a])` that returns both the init and the last element of the list?

Comment: the program works in a way that it stores a value  then from that value a number is removed using init. Now as we go further into the program other things happen such as doubling elements and adding them. Finally I use mod again after all the doubling and adding etc has been done. I want to Check whether this mod number I have taken is equivalent to that when I originally removed a number earlier in the program. then if the original number that was removed equals the final mod number I want to print true else false

Comment: `finalcheck` doesn't have the element it needs. So you need to fix that. Most likely, you should pass it the "removed" element as a separate argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you remove data, you can't access it again. You need a function that preserves the final checkdigit that you're stripping off.

Since order is (mostly) irrelevant, consider:

```
validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate x = let digits = toDigits x
             in  if   checkLength digits
                 then doesMatch . splitCheckdigit $ digits
                 else False
  where
  toDigits 0 = [0]
  toDigits x = go x
    where
    go 0 = []
    go x = let (d, m) = x `divMod` 10
           in  m : toDigits d
  -- reverses order
  checkLength x = let l = length x
                  in  13 <= l && l <= 16
  splitCheckdigit (checkdigit:rest) = (checkdigit, rest)
  -- remember we reversed in toDigits, so the *first* digit is the checkdigit!
  doesMatch (checkdigit, rest) = let total    = (*9) . sum . reduce $ rest
                                     shouldBe = total `mod` 10
                                 in  checkdigit == shouldBe
    where
    reduce (x:y:xs) = (sum . toDigits $ x) : y : reduce xs
    reduce [x]      = [sum . toDigits $ x]
    reduce []       = []
    -- note how @toDigits@ is reused here rather than redefined.
```

If you prefer Arrows, `validate` can be written as:

```
toDigits >>> ((doesMatch <<< splitCheckdigit) &&& checkLength) >>> uncurry (&&)
```